# android text view(s) overlayed with button

Tags: android, android-layout, button, overlay, transparent

within a linear layout i need to overlay some text views with a transparent button which fills the whole layout size (width/height). I tried with match parent layout properties but that doesn't work. Thank You for your help.

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout1"
                android:layout_width="38dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TVBlack"
                    android:layout_width="28dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:background="@color/black"
                    android:text="test"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TVWhite"
                    android:layout_width="28dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:text="test"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:text="Button" />

            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: As others have already answered: creating overlays within a `LinearLayout` is not possible. In stead I would just convert the whole thing into a `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: I don't think a `RelativeLayout` will do the job, if you centre two items it will place them side by side in the centre.

Comment: @P-double: A `RelativeLayout` most certainly does not what you're describing. Pick any answered question regarding `RelativeLayout` and overla(y)(pp)ing views on SO and you'll see that. As a matter of fact: why don't you try it out and see for yourself that the widgets  are placed on top of each other (depth-wise). :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible with a Linear Layout, it will not overlay objects on top of each other, it will just place objects side-by-side in the order they are declared. You need to use a `FrameLayout` to achieve what you've described, see the docs here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html